# Oracle APEX - How to hide tooltip for one series in a stacked bar chart

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-19.1

I am using Oracle APEX 19.1.0.00.15 and I have a question regarding tooltips for a stacked bar chart. I have created a stacked bar chart that consists of three series, but I would only like for the tooltip to be rendered for two of the series. I see that there is an option in the chart's Attributes section to hide or show the tooltip for the chart as a whole, but not for individual series within the chart. I have tried to find the relevant JavaScript for the tooltip in the Oracle JavaScript Extension Toolkit API Reference http://https://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jet/jsdocs/oj.ojChart.html but I was not able to find anything useful. Does anyone have any advice for how to achieve this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set shortDesc attribute for each item of the series to an empty string.

You can do that in initialization phase using the following code:

```
function( options ){
    options.dataFilter = function( data ) {
        var l_items = data.series[ 0 ].items
        for (var i=0; i<l_items.length; i++) {
            l_items[i].shortDesc = "";
        }        
        return data;
    };    
    return options;
}
```

The above code will disable tooltip for the items of the first series.